# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide; Runtime Error

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using latest [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) Library for Android. On Compile time there is no error but when the app is installed on device it shows this error in runtime:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/bumptech/glide/Glide;

I included the following modules as stated in the `Glide` official Github Page:

`compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0' compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0'`

Still the error persists.

[Glide Github Link](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.esmartify"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        multiDexEnabled true

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: '*.jar', dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.0.2'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.1'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.22.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.5.1'
    debugCompile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.5.0'
    debugCompile 'com.uphyca:stetho_realm:2.1.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

EDIT: I think the problem lies somewhere else as using Picasso instead of Glide throws the same error as `Picasso java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Looks like a version dependency error

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'` try using v7

Comment: I have tried every possible combination of the versions. Still no success

Comment: @sagarsuri Yes I have this included too.

Comment: does it show any line in your `Activity` in the logcat ?

Comment: It doesn't show any compile error. Lint also passes the code without even a warning. On runtime though, the app crashes

Comment: Are you using proguard / do you have minifyEnabled set to true in your build.gradle?

Comment: @Thys Yes! I have minifyEnabled set to true in release section of build.gradle.

Comment: I recommend you to post an sample empty project where you can reproduce the issue on github so we'll help you correctly ;)

Comment: I don't see any references to glide in your gradle file? Is that on ./lib? Also I'd suggest not using version 4.0.0 to solve this problem, versions ending in .0.0 have a tendency to show more problems.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same issue, adding the transitive = true field did the trick

```
compile ('com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check you've added `mavenCentral()` in your `build.gradle` file

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Yes I have mavenCentral() in build.gradle. During Compilation time Glide is getting recognized and there is no compilation error. Only during the runtime the Glide is not recognized.

Comment: Let me try again let you know

Comment: Sure! I am stuck on this for the last 2 days. Thanks!

Comment: Can you create a sample project and host it on github or somewhere we can have a look because for me it's working fine.

Comment: I tried to replace Glide with Picasso. The error is still coming say but this time saying Picasso ClassDefNotFound !!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following lines to your proguard-rules.pro;

```
-keep class com.bumptech.** {*;}
-keepclassmembers class com.bumptech.** {*;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you already have this glide version or class in your project due to which you are getting no class def error. Try to check all the dependencies jar classes with jdgui.